# Using Java code in antlr grammar g4 file

Tags: java, parsing, enums, antlr4

I would like to define a grammar that should parse words that are related to units of measure e.g. for kilograms: 'kg', 'KG', 'kilogram', 'kilograms', 'l', 'liters', 'litres' etc.

I am already doing something similar using a Java `enum` class to validate input strings supposed to represent a unit of measure.

I was wondering if it's possible to reuse the already defined units of measure in the enum class inside the ANTLR grammar file. Basically I would like to set a **lexer** in a **.g4** grammar file like:

```
UNITS: UnitMeasures.values()
```

Where the `.values()` method returns the enum values inside the `UnitMeasures` enum Java class, this "should be equivalent" to ANTLR grammar lexer:

```
UNITS: ('kg' | 'KG' | 'kilograms' | 'l' | 'litres' | 'liters' );
```

The **reasons** why I am trying to do this are:

- I would like to **avoid code duplication** between the enum Java class and the ANTLR grammar file;
- I can not use only ANTLR and delete the enum Java class as it is already used in many different places;
- Now I am trying to use the units of measure in a more complex scenario where I need to parse amounts, units of measures and other related stuff, so I decided to use ANTLR.

Is it possible to avoid this code duplication somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the enums were not already present in your program, I would suggest generating runtime artifacts based on the grammar itself.

Since you already have the enums defined, let's implement unit recognition after parsing is complete with an [AbstractParseTreeVisitor](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Java/src/org/antlr/v4/runtime/tree/AbstractParseTreeVisitor.java).

**1)**
Add a `units` parser rule and generalize your `UNITS` lexer rule:

```
...

unit : ID
     ;

...

ID: [a-zA-Z_0-9]+ ; // whatever you want/need 

...
```

Now your grammar does not duplicate any code, but your rule for units is too general. We will solve this on the java side of things.

**2)**
Generate a visitor and override `visitUnit(UnitContext)`.

```
@Override
public Object visitUnit(UnitContext ctx) {

    String unitId = ctx.ID();

    try{ 
         // Next line will throw exception if unitId is not
         // the name of one of your enums.
         UnitMeasures unit = UnitMeasures.valueOf(unitId);

         // do something maybe?

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException(e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Invalid unit: " + unitId);
    }

    return super.visitUnit(ctx);
}
```

This will eliminate any code duplication. Now, any time you add a new enum to `UnitMeasures`, you don't have to alter your grammar. You won't even need to regenerate your parser.

**Another option:**
This will add a java dependency to your grammar, but you could add a little action right after your `unit` rule which could respond appropriately if the `ID` was not a valid unit based on your `enum`.

```
unit : ID 
     { 
         try {
             UnitMeasures.valueOf($unit.text);
         }
         catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
             //report invalid unit
         }
     }
     ;
```